# Cant figure out why my modal isnt displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am currently working on a personal portfolio site and i'm not sure why my modal is not displaying. When you click on `view more` , it should display:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl9HF.png)

however, nothing happens. I have it appearing here in this pic by commenting out the opacity and visibility on lines 645 & 646 on my css.
[This is the code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/zee225/pen/abGBWEe)

The code for this basically starts in the Services section at

html line: 648

css : 592

js: 65

I dont get an errors in my console which throws me off.

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

ps, this is being done in mobile view first, so i suggest adjusting the codepen screen to a smaller size.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside your question, please do not just dump the whole thing onto an external platform like codepen.

Comment: typo ... `active-modal` vs `active_modal`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding class - 'active-modal' by js and in css classname is 'active_modal'

Class name is not matching. Kindly correct it. It will work as expected.